# Problem creating a forwarding rule for iptables from shorewall firewall?

Tags: linux, firewall, shorewall

I'm trying to get my shorewall firewall to put an additional simple "FORWARD" rule in iptables. I've never had a need to put a forwarding rule in my /etc/shorewall/rules file, but now I'm trying to for my WIREGUARD VPN. I've put plenty of input/output rules in it before, but I can't quite figure it out for forwarding.

"When" the Wireguard service starts it creates an interface called,
wg0

So, can someone show me the shorewall rule I should write to make it create two rules resulting
in iptables having a rule that shows in iptables as,

```
-A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
and
-A FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the zone (or use an existing one) in `/etc/shorewall/zones`.

Add the interface `wg0` to the zone in `/etc/shorewall/interfaces`. For example, let's assume the zone is named `zonewg0`.

Add policy to `/etc/shorewall/policy` along:

```
ALL zonewg0 ACCEPT
zonewg0 ALL ACCEPT
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Before I try it I think I need to refine it a bit so I don't get locked out of my cloud server if Wireguard goes down. Will this work?  ALL zonewg0 ACCEPT udp 5xxxxx   and  zonewg0 ALL ACCEPT udp 5xxxxx

Comment: `o I don't get locked out` always have many stand-by ssh sessions opened. Usually all firewall filter new connections, existing ones are not touched. `ALL zonewg0 ACCEPT udp 5xxxxx` I do not understand that, the `policy` file 3rd column is LOGLEVEL. If you want to enable udp traffic only, use `rules` file.